# ID parameter in Django REST API URL

Tags: django, api, rest, url, django-rest-viewsets

I have two models:

1. Article
2. Comment

Comments are connected to Article with ForeingKey.

I want to create an endpoint like:

```
       {GET} /article/97/comments  # get all comments of article (id:97)
       {POST} /article/97/comments  # create an comment for article (id=97)
```

But I want to use GenericViewSet or ModelMixins.

Can you guide me, how can I do so?

Thanks.

Comment: https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers

Comment: @IainShelvington, That seems great source. I am looking right now. Thanks. I hope it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very simple using nested routes:

Define your Article model (`models/article.py`):

```py
class Article(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default='')
    ...
```

Define your Comment model (`models/comment.py`):

```py
class Comment(models.Model):
    content = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False, default='')
    article = models.ForeignKey(Article, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    ...
```

Define your Article view (`views/article.py`):

```py
class ArticleAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = ArticleSerializer
    ....
```

Define your Comment view (`views/comment.py`):

```py
class CommentAPIView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CommentSerializer
    ...
```

Define your routes (`urls.py`):

```py
from django.urls import path
from app.domain.api import views
from rest_framework_extensions.routers import ExtendedSimpleRouter

urlpatterns: list = []

router: ExtendedSimpleRouter = ExtendedSimpleRouter()
articles_router = router.register('articles', views.ArticleAPIView, basename='articles')
articles_router.register(
    'comments',
    views.CommentAPIView,
    basename='comments',
    parents_query_lookups=['article']
)
urlpatterns += router.urls
```

You will get routes for articles like:

```
{GET} /articles/          -> Get list
{GET} /articles/{id}/     -> Get by id
{POST} /articles/         -> Create
{PUT} /articles/{id}/     -> Update
{PATCH} /articles/{id}/   -> Partial update
{DELETE} /articles/{id}/  -> Delete
```

Finally, you will get routes for comments like:

```
{GET} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/          -> Get list
{GET} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/{id}/     -> Get by id
{POST} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/         -> Create
{PUT} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/{id}/     -> Update
{PATCH} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/{id}/   -> Partial update
{DELETE} /articles/{parent_lookup_article}/comments/{id}/  -> Delete
```